# Promisify Express response.render method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, node-promisify

I need to create a render method to build html blocks into a string.
It seems to work but I used the notorious "new Promise" and I wanted to know if what I've done is either correct or not:

```
async render(req, res) {
  const locals = await this.execute(req); // DB operation, retrieve context
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      return res.render('my-view', { ...locals, layout: null }, (err, html) => { 
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        return resolve(html);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new Promise` constructor implicitly catches (synchronous) exceptions from the executor callback, so that `try`/`catch` is not needed. Also, the `return` value is ignored. You'd write just

```
async render(req, res) {
  const locals = await this.execute(req); // DB operation, retrieve context
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    res.render('my-view', { ...locals, layout: null }, (err, html) => { 
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(html);
    });
  });
}
```